# A linux shell script to find a string and add a few lines before the string

Tags: linux, string, shell, sed

I'm new to this, just wondering if anyone could help :)

I have a file like this:

```
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
end1
```

How do I find the string end1 and add a few lines before the string, so it looks like:

```
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
NaN  
NaN  
end1
```

But the number of line added has to depend on a specific number, say 5. If it only has 3 entries between start1 and end1, the numbers of line added is 2.

Comment: You can use tail -2 filename | head -1 to get the penultimate line.
From there, I guess you can easily write a shell script the use the string value of that line and the value of the last line.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not clear whether that number you mention is always something you figure out from the file contents or something you might program but try this:

```
awk '
/start/ { c=0 }
/end/   { for (i=1; i<c; i++) print "NaN" }
{ print; ++c }
' file
```

and let us know of any problems.

EDIT: to add c lines if less than 5 lines exist:

```
awk '
/start/ { c=0 }
/end/ && c<5  { for (i=1; i<c; i++) print "NaN" }
{ print; ++c }
' file
```

or to pad up to 5 lines:

```
awk '
/start/ { c=0 }
/end/   { for (i=c; i<=5; i++) print "NaN" }
{ print; ++c }
' file
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I'm sorry I wasn't being very clear. I need to first check the number of entries between start1 and end1. And if the number of entry is less than 5, I need to add extra lines. So I do something like count=`awk'/start1/{c=-2}{c++}/end1/{print c}' <inputfile  if [ "$count" -ne 5]

Comment: if ["$count" -ne 5] then add"NaN"

Comment: Then just test the counter variable, c. I'll update my script now to show that.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with `awk(1)`:

```
awk '/start1/ {start=NR} /end1/ && start {for (i=NR-start;i<=5;++i) {print "NaN"}} 1'
```

That will record which line the string `start1` was on, and when it sees the line the string `end1`, it will output up to 5 lines of NaN depending on how far apart `start1` and `end1` are. Change the 5 to be whatever you need.

Comment: This works fine for me, it's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks camh :) xxx

Comment: nice idea to save the line number. you might want to pass the value 5 with the `-v` option

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vt=5 '/start1/{print;next;}/end1/{for(x=1;x<=t-i;x++)print "NaN";}++i' file
```

you just replace the 5 in above one-liner to get different number of "NaN" :)

EDIT: start may not at 1st line.

```
awk -vt=5 '/start1/{i=0;print;next;}/end1/{for(x=1;x<=t-i;x++)print "NaN";}++i' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat t
Empty lines followed




foo
foo1
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
end1
bar
bar2

kent$  awk -vt=5 '/start1/{i=0;print;next;}/end1/{for(x=1;x<=t-i;x++)print "NaN";}++i' t
Empty lines followed




foo
foo1
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
NaN
NaN
end1
bar
bar2
```

Comment: This assumes that `start1` is on the first line, whereas the question asks only about the number of entries between `start` and `end1`, not their position in the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!! :D xxx But does this depend on whether the start is on the first line? I need to actually find the the string start1...

Comment: @Babycece yes, I assumed that "start1" is sitting at the 1st line. add `i=0;` to /start1/ block should solve it, I will update the answer

Comment: Another stupid question: how do I read from a file and output it back in the same file? :)

Comment: @Babycece with awk you cannot do it directly (not like sed -i), however you could redirect output to a tmp file and then mv it back to your original back. (please make a backup). the cmd looks like `awk 'blahblah' /path/myfile >/tmp/t.tmp && mv -f /tmp/t.tmp /path/myfile`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! Thanks a lot Kent! xxx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to do such a thing:

```
`sed /end1/lineToAdd0\nlineToAdd1\netc\nend1/g < file`
```

I’m not sure about the `\n`, I don’t remember if it’s `sed` that interprets it a special way.

Comment: The portable way to represent a newline in sed is an escaped <return>.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I do not know a straightforward way to do what you want with Sed.  Someone will probably post an Awk answer, which is fine, but if one does not mind the run-time cost of starting the Perl interpreter, this works, too:

```
perl -we 'print until eof() or ($_ = <>) =~ /^start1\s*$/; exit if eof(); print; my $i = 5; --$i, print until eof() or ($_ = <>) =~ /^end1\s*$/; --$i, print "NaN\n" until $i <= 0; print; print <>;'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited to `awk` just set `c` to the number you require:

```
$ awk -vc=5 '/start/{n=0}/end/{for(i=0;i++<c+1-n;)print"NaN"}++n' file
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
NaN
NaN
end1

$ awk -vc=8 '/start/{n=0}/end/{for(i=0;i++<c+1-n;)print"NaN"}++n' file
start1  
12.3  
13.2  
15.3  
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
end1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^start/!b;n;:a;/\nend/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;/(\n[^\n]*){5}/!s/$/\nNaN/;tb;s/(\nend[^\n]*)(.*)/\2\1/' file
```